Why did the raiders leave Vault 33 in the first episode of "Fallout"?
I'm new to the Fallout series and just began watching the TV show. 
My question is simple: Why did the raiders leave Vault 33? One can argue that they want the vault's overseer, but why not leave someone in charge? It seems that the raiders were in very bad shape, having been (surviving) from outside. At Vault 33, they have access to a relative amount of shelter, food, and water. Why give the vault back?

They didn't give the vault back, they were defeated and the held captive

@A.Steer some of them were captured, some of them chose to leave after giving the Vault overseer a decision to make and then setting off a bomb.  Those captured were likely defeated after the other group left - the bomb blocked the exit to the other Vault afterall.

To the OP - this is largely answered later on in the series.

@Moo do we know for certain that those who left where raiders, or where they individuals who where part of the other faction at the observatory (trying to keep it spoiler free)

@A.Steer exactly.

Looked like they gave it up to me. Just finished episode 1 (i played fallout 3 and new vegas only) and its really not clear. I hope it starts to make sense i am fed up with shit tv programs i looked forward to.

@HubertBlu This series is largely based on mystery and reveals. Who the leader of "raiders" was and why kidnap overseer is one of them. The series is pretty good, but needs some patience, I guess.

On episode 3 now and really enjoying it! Thank the heavens. Think im just super impatient

As the season unfolds, it will become clear that Moldaver, the raiders’ leader, had a singular focus:

to capture Hank MacLean, the overseer of Vault 33. Her goal was to obtain the code for the Cold Fusion technology, a project that predated the Great War and one she’s been determined to reclaim. (Hank, for reasons to be revealed later in the season, holds the key to the code.)

For Moldaver, Vault 33 itself held no value; it was merely a means to an end. She has what she came for, and her crew follows orders—even if it means abandoning a perfectly good shelter with food and water. This explains why they readily leave Vault 33 after securing their target.
